# PHP and HTML Forms

Tags: php, html, forms

so this is part of my code...

> ```
> <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
>    Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $FirstName;?>">
> </form>
> ```

but when you view it on a browser, because there is double use of '>' it thinks thats the end of the tag so the 2nd '>' will show on the browser making the form not work..

anyone know why it does this? and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use this way: ... $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ...

Comment: I checked this and it works

Comment: thanks heaps cant believe i didnt think of that. but also having an issue with a similar thing.. 

Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $FirstName;?>">

the value ends up being the php code

Comment: never mind all has been fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Refering to part of your question in the above comments 'but also having an issue with a similar thing.. '

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $FirstName;?>">
```

the value ends up being the php code –

The solution to this is at the top of your page write

```
    <?php   $FirstName="";     ?>
```

and then inside the table.....

```
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" value='<?php echo $FirstName;?>' >
```

Hope this works.....